# Eigenvalues, show that $\lambda_1+ \lambda_2 = a + d , \lambda_1.\lambda_2 = |A| $

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> **[10 points]** Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix with real eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$. Show that $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=a+d$ and $\lambda_1 \cdot \lambda_2=|A|$.

This is an old exam question. I couldn't figure out how to do it. This is what I did so far:
$$(a-\lambda)\cdot (d-\lambda)-b\cdot c$$
But I could not figure out how to continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(a-\lambda).(d-\lambda)-b.c\to\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda +ad-bc=0\to\\
\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda +\det(A)=0\quad (1)$$

If $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the roots then

$$(\lambda-\lambda_1)(\lambda-\lambda_2)=0\to \lambda^2-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)\lambda +\lambda_1\cdot \lambda_2=0\quad (2)$$

Now compare $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: To complete this answer, perhaps one should add that that the characteristic polynomial can also be written as $(\lambda_1-\lambda)(\lambda_2-\lambda)=\lambda^2-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)\lambda+\lambda_1\lambda_2$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I wrote at the same time that you. Thanks anyway.